# Random code#404 error problem

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404

I have a multisite setup which works just fine with existing live and test websites. The multisite is hosted on a private VPS of mine.
I began hosting a new clients website a few days ago and very bizzarly the entire site randomly goes from
live and working to a 404 error page.

Would anyone please offer any insights into what could be the problem?

Comment: It could be a huge number of things. Did you change anything recently? Is there a chance the hosting provider changed or upgraded anything?